# Tomcat 10, Java 17 - JavaMailSender cannot cast one of elements of java.lang.Object[]

Tags: spring-boot, cxf, java-17, tomcat10, javax.activation

After migrating application to Spring Boot 3 and Java 17 I tried to deploy it to Tomcat 10.1.x.

The deployment failed with exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'mailSender' defined in class path
> resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfig
> ure/mail/MailSenderPropertiesConfiguration.class]: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl]:
> Factory method 'mailSender' threw exception with message:  arraycopy:
> element type mismatch: can not cast one of the elements of
> java.lang.Object[] to the type of the destination array,
> jakarta.activation.MimeTypeRegistry

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be caused by CXF library having dependency on:
com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation.

The solution is to exclude it from cxf:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Instead include directly the jakarta.activation-api as below:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

There might be other libraries with the same dependency in the application.

For above the approach with deploying application to webapps-javaee folder and allowing Tomcat to perform migration doesn't work.