# JavaMailSender cannot cast one of elements of java.lang.Object[]

Tags: spring-boot, java-17, spring-boot-starter

After migrating to Spring Boot 3 from 2.6.9, I am encountering the following error.

Root cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: arraycopy: element type mismatch: can not cast one of the elements of java.lang.Object[] to the type of the destination array, jakarta.activation.MimeTypeRegistry
    at java.base/java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.copyInto(Vector.java:205)
    at jakarta.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap.<init>(MimetypesFileTypeMap.java:140)
    at jakarta.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap.<init>(MimetypesFileTypeMap.java:312)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.createFileTypeMap(ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.java:150)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.getFileTypeMap(ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.java:123)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.afterPropertiesSet(ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.java:110)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.<init>(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderPropertiesConfiguration.mailSender(MailSenderPropertiesConfiguration.java:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
    ... 74 common frames omitted
```

I have added following two dependencies as a solution suggested by other Stack Overflow answers, but that didn't work.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>${jaxb-runtime.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I also tried solution provided by [Tomcat 10, Java 17 - JavaMailSender cannot cast one of elements of java.lang.Object[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75344808/tomcat-10-java-17-javamailsender-cannot-cast-one-of-elements-of-java-lang-obj) and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33452, which didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Spring Boot, but i am using Java 17, Tomcat 10 and Jakarta EE 10 and I had the same error.

The error is caused by the lack of "jakarta.activation.MimeTypeRegistry" which is part of the "jakarta.activation-api"

I was able to send the email using the next dependencies:

```xml
<!-- START Jakarta email support -->

<!-- https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/ -->
<!-- https://github.com/jakartaee/mail-api -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.mail/jakarta.mail-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/angus-mail -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.angus/jakarta.mail -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.activation/jakarta.activation-api -->        
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- END Jakarta email support -->
```

I hope it helps, at least it could help EE users.

HappyCoding;

Answer (score -1):

Check one's by adding below dependency

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is already present !!