# arraycopy: element type mismatch: can not cast when sending email using Kotlin and Jakarta.email

Tags: kotlin, email

I'm trying to test the delivery of an email via Gmail using Kotlin but when I run the project, a console project, I get the error

`arraycopy: element type mismatch: can not cast one of the elements of java.lang.Object[] to the type of the destination array, jakarta.activation.MailcapRegistry`

The code is quite straightforward. This is the main.kt file:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // Testing email
    val mailService = MailService()
    mailService.sendEmail("aaa.bbb@gmail.com",
        "aaa.bbb@gmail.com", "Test", "This is a test")
}
```

and the MailService class is the following:

```
import jakarta.mail.MessagingException
import jakarta.mail.Authenticator
import jakarta.mail.Message
import jakarta.mail.PasswordAuthentication
import jakarta.mail.Session
import jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage
import java.util.*

class MailService {
    private val session : Session

    init {
        val username = "aaa.bbb@gmail.com"
        val password = "123456789"

        val properties = Properties()
        properties["mail.smtp.host"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
        properties["mail.smtp.port"] = "587"
        properties["mail.smtp.auth"] = "true";
        properties["mail.smtp.starttls.enable"] = "true"; //TLS

        val authenticator = object : Authenticator() {
            override fun getPasswordAuthentication() : PasswordAuthentication {
                return PasswordAuthentication(username, password)
            }
        }
        session = Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator)
        session.debug = true
    }

    fun sendEmail(fromEmailAddress : String,
                toEmailAddress : String,
                subject : String,
                bodyText : String) : Unit {
        try {
            var email = MimeMessage(session);

            email.setFrom(InternetAddress(fromEmailAddress, false));
            email.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress(toEmailAddress, false));
            email.subject = subject
            email.setText(bodyText)

            val smtpTransport = session.getTransport("smtp")
            smtpTransport.connect()
            smtpTransport.sendMessage(email, email.allRecipients)
            smtpTransport.close()
        }
        catch (messagingException: MessagingException) {
            messagingException.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

and these are the dependencies in the POM file:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.mail/jakarta.mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/angus-mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I tried the solution [Tomcat 10, Java 17 - JavaMailSender cannot cast one of elements of java.lang.Object[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75344808/tomcat-10-java-17-javamailsender-cannot-cast-one-of-elements-of-java-lang-obj) but it didn't work.
I'm not getting anymore ideas where the problem is. It might be that the issue is under my nose but I'm not seeing it :-)
Any suggestion?
Thank you.

Comment: I tried to use the [setContent()](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/1.6/apidocs/javax/mail/internet/mimemessage#setContent-javax.mail.Multipart-) method to set the content of the email instead of using the [setText()](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/1.6/apidocs/javax/mail/internet/mimemessage#setText-java.lang.String-) that uses MIME type of "text/plain", and the code is now working.